# How to generate custom SOAP fault message detail from ABAP inbound adapter

Tags: soap, abap, sap-pi

Using ABAP we created a service provider and on certain condition the service should send SOAP Fault message which needs to have details like the error code and error description etc..standard ABAP implementation would not allow sending this error. Tried sending regular exception with the type of structure with the required fields but it not passed further to the client.

tried passing the CL_SOAP_FAULT_11 object to the exception CX_SOAP_FAULT. it somehow is eaten up by the standard code sending just the empty soap body.

This service is built in R/3 and not PI

Comment: show your code maybe, it's hard to guess what and how you done it

Comment: When this service is not build on PI, why did you tag the question PI? What does PI mean here anyway? Do you mean the product SAP Process Integration (which was renamed to [Process Orchestration](https://www.sap.com/products/process-orchestration.html) a while ago)? Is it involved here somehow?

Comment: PI/XI System is build on abap and should be using the same classes. I have seen  it is possible to use fault messages to pass custom error tags. So any light on it would be useful

Comment: There is nothing to code for Exception in implementation of generated class/methods. Any exception on these methods would throw the error but no control on the structure of the error tags.